# TFIDF separate for each label

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Using TFIDFvectorizor(SKlearn), how to obtain word ranking based on tfidf score for each label separately. I want the word frequency for each label (positive and negative).

relevant code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,stop_words='english',use_idf=True, ngram_range =(1,1))
features_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(features_train).todense()
features_test = vectorizer.transform(features_test).todense()


for i in range(len(features_test)):
    first_document_vector=features_test[i]
    df_t = pd.DataFrame(first_document_vector.T, index=feature_names, columns=["tfidf"])


df_t.sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False).head(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you positive, neutral, and negative sentiment analysis for each row of comments in a field of a dataframe.  There is a lot of preprocessing code, to get things cleaned up, filter out stop-words, do some basic charting, etc.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re
import nltk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
global str

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\test_dataset.csv')

print(df.shape)


# let's experiment with some sentiment analysis concepts
# first we need to clean up the stuff in the independent field of the DF we are workign with
df['body'] = df[['body']].astype(str)
df['review_text'] = df[['review_text']].astype(str)

df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace('\d+', '')
# get rid of special characters
df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
# get rid fo double spaces
df['body'] = df['body'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')
# convert all case to lower
df['body'] = df['body'].str.lower()
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.lower()


# It looks like the language in body and review_text is very similar (2 fields in dataframe).  let's check how closely they match...
# seems like the tone is similar, but the text is not matching at a high rate...less than 20% match rate
import difflib

body_list = df['body'].tolist()
review_text_list = df['review_text'].tolist()

body = body_list     
reviews = review_text_list
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, body, reviews).ratio()
print ("ratio:", s, "\n")



# filter out stop words
# these are the most common words such as: “the“, “a“, and “is“.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords   
english_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
print(len(english_stopwords))
text = str(body_list)
# split into words
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
# convert to lower case
tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
# remove punctuation from each word
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
# remove remaining tokens that are not alphabetic
words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
# filter out stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
print(words[:100])


# plot most frequently occurring words in a bar chart
# remove unwanted characters, numbers and symbols
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].str.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", " ")

#Let’s try to remove the stopwords and short words (<2 letters) from the reviews.
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

# function to remove stopwords
def remove_stopwords(rev):
    rev_new = " ".join([i for i in rev if i not in stop_words])
    return rev_new

# remove short words (length < 3)
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if len(w)>2]))

# remove stopwords from the text
reviews = [remove_stopwords(r.split()) for r in df['review_text']]

# make entire text lowercase
reviews = [r.lower() for r in reviews]

#Let’s again plot the most frequent words and see if the more significant words have come out.
freq_words(reviews, 35)


###############################################################################
###############################################################################
# Tf-idf is a very common technique for determining roughly what each document in a set of 
# documents is “about”. It cleverly accomplishes this by looking at two simple metrics: tf 
# (term frequency) and idf (inverse document frequency). Term frequency is the proportion 
# of occurrences of a specific term to total number of terms in a document. Inverse document 
# frequency is the inverse of the proportion of documents that contain that word/phrase. 
# Simple, right!? The general idea is that if a specific phrase appears a lot of times in a 
# given document, but it doesn’t appear in many other documents, then we have a good idea 
# that the phrase is important in distinguishing that document from all the others. 
# Starting with the CountVectorizer/TfidfTransformer approach...
# convert fields in datframe to list


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=1, max_df=.5, ngram_range=(1,2))
cvec

# Calculate all the n-grams found in all documents
from itertools import islice
cvec.fit(body_list)
list(islice(cvec.vocabulary_.items(), 20))

len(cvec.vocabulary_)

# Let’s take a moment to describe these parameters as they are the primary levers for adjusting what 
# feature set we end up with. First is “min_df” or mimimum document frequency. This sets the minimum 
# number of documents that any term is contained in. This can either be an integer which sets the 
# number specifically, or a decimal between 0 and 1 which is interpreted as a percentage of all documents. 
# Next is “max_df” which similarly controls the maximum number of documents any term can be found in. 
# If 90% of documents contain the word “spork” then it’s so common that it’s not very useful.
# Initialize the vectorizer with new settings and check the new vocabulary length
cvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english', min_df=.0025, max_df=.5, ngram_range=(1,2))
cvec.fit(body_list)
len(cvec.vocabulary_)

# Our next move is to transform the document into a “bag of words” representation which essentially is 
# just a separate column for each term containing the count within each document. After that, we’ll 
# take a look at the sparsity of this representation which lets us know how many nonzero values there 
# are in the dataset. The more sparse the data is the more challenging it will be to model
cvec_counts = cvec.transform(body_list)
print('sparse matrix shape:', cvec_counts.shape)
print('nonzero count:', cvec_counts.nnz)
print('sparsity: %.2f%%' % (100.0 * cvec_counts.nnz / (cvec_counts.shape[0] * cvec_counts.shape[1])))



# get counts of frequently occurring terms; top 20
occ = np.asarray(cvec_counts.sum(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
counts_df = pd.DataFrame({'term': cvec.get_feature_names(), 'occurrences': occ})
counts_df.sort_values(by='occurrences', ascending=False).head(20)

# Now that we’ve got term counts for each document we can use the TfidfTransformer to calculate the 
# weights for each term in each document 
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
transformed_weights = transformer.fit_transform(cvec_counts)
transformed_weights


# we can take a look at the top 20 terms by average tf-idf weight.
weights = np.asarray(transformed_weights.mean(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
weights_df = pd.DataFrame({'term': cvec.get_feature_names(), 'weight': weights})
weights_df.sort_values(by='weight', ascending=False).head(20)


# FINALLY!!!!
# Here we are doing some sentiment analysis, and distilling the 'review_text' field into positive, neutral, or negative, 
# based on the tone of the text in each record.  Also, we are filtering out the records that have <.2 negative score; 
# keeping only those that have >.2 negative score. This is interesting, but this can contain some non-intitive results.  
# For instance, one record in 'review_text' literally says 'no issues'.  This is probably positive, but the algo sees the
# word 'no' and interprets the comment as negative.  I would argue that it's positive.  We'll circle back and resolve 
# this potential issue a little later.
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('punkt')



from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
def convert(x):
    if x < 0:
        return "negative"
    elif x > .2:
        return "positive"
    else:
        return "neutral"
df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))


# df.groupby(['brand','result']).size()
# df.groupby(['brand','result']).count()
x = df.groupby(['review_text','brand'])['result'].value_counts(normalize=True)

x = df.groupby(['brand'])['result'].value_counts(normalize=True)
y = x.loc[(x.index.get_level_values(1) == 'negative')]
print(y[y>0.2])
```

Result:

```
brand                         result  
ABH                           negative    0.500000
Alexander McQueen             negative    0.500000
Anastasia                     negative    0.498008
BURBERRY                      negative    0.248092
Beats                         negative    0.272947
Bowers & Wilkins              negative    0.500000
Breitling Official            negative    0.666667
Capri Blue                    negative    0.333333
FERRARI                       negative    1.000000
Fendi                         negative    0.283582
GIORGIO ARMANI                negative    1.000000
Jan Marini Skin Research      negative    0.250000
Jaybird                       negative    0.235294
LANCï¿½ME                     negative    0.500000
Longchamp                     negative    0.271605
Longchamps                    negative    0.500000
M.A.C                         negative    0.203390
Meaningful Beauty             negative    0.222222
Polk Audio                    negative    0.256410
Pumas                         negative    0.222222
Ralph Lauren Polo             negative    0.500000
Roberto Cavalli               negative    0.250000
Samsung                       negative    0.332298
T3 Micro                      negative    0.224138
Too Faced                     negative    0.216216
VALENTINO by Mario Valentino  negative    0.333333
YSL                           negative    0.250000
```

Feel free to skip things you find to be irrelevant, but as-is, the code does a fairly comprehensive NLP analysis.

Also, take a look at these two links.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/the-different-methods-deal-text-data-predictive-python/

https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-grained-sentiment-analysis-in-python-part-1-2697bb111ed4